# Nefness property for symplectic equivalency of Moishezon manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, minimal-model-program

**Definition**:Two symplectic manifolds $(X,\omega_X)$ and $(Y,\omega_Y)$ are defined to be symplectically equivalent if there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi:X\to Y$ such that $\phi^∗ω_Y$ is in the same deformation class as $\omega_X$.

A line bundle $L$ over  compact complex manifold $X$ is said to be nef(in the sense of Demaily) if for every $ε>0$ there exists a smooth hermitian metric $h_\epsilon$ on $L$ such that its curvature $Θ_{h_\epsilon}(L)≥−\epsilon ω$ . The good thing is that this definition even work for Moishezon manifold due to [Mihai Paun](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002080050154). So my following question make sense

[We know](http://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0021/0006/a007/)  if $X$ and $Y$ are symplectically equivalent compact Kähler threefolds then $X$ has an algebraically nef canonical bundle if and only if the same is true for $Y$. See also  [Peternell-Höring paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-015-0592-x) and [Voisin](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eclaire.voisin/Articlesweb/fanosymp.pdf) paper as introductions.

In fact this is the extension of the [result of Y. Ruan](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01896262?LI=true)
when $X$ and $Y$ are projective  by  Gromov-Witten invariant.

**Question**: Is there any same result when the symplectic manifolds $(X,\omega_X)$ and $(Y,\omega_Y)$ are Moishezon manifolds(here I mean nefness in numerical sense)? .

**Motivation**: Every Moishezon variety which is not projective contains a rational curve.  Kollar conjectured : Assume $X$ is rationally connected. Let $Y$ be a compact Kahler manifold symplectically equivalent to $X$. Then $Y$ is also rationally connected. I believe that attacking to these conjectures by analytical tools correspond to relative Kahler Ricci flow which connect Gromov-Witten theory to study of Relative Kahler Ricci flow.

Comment: If a Moishezon manifold has a symplectic form that is compatible with the almost complex structure, then the manifold is projective.